# VS 2019 stricmp and _stricmp both cause compiler error

Tags: c++, c++14, case

The source code itself isn't really in question. It's the compiler's reaction to it. Here's the troublesome snippet:

```
int XtnUtil::IsExtension(const char * filename, const char * xtn)
{
    char*   fx  =   FindExtension(filename);    //  Get a pointer to the filename extension
    if  (!fx)   return  0;                      //  Bail out if it's not there

    if  (xtn[0] == '.') xtn++;                  //  Make sure we're looking at the alpha part
    return  (stricmp(fx, xtn) ? 0 : 1);     //  TRUE if they're equal
}
```

I've also used `_stricmp` instead of `stricmp`. In either case, the compiler gives me a particularly uninformative message:
[image: weird error message]

It seems to say "Don't use _stricmp, use _stricmp instead." I tried it with and without the underscore and also tried the POSIX equivalent, `strcasecmp()` but Visual Studio doesn't seem to know that function at all.

For the moment, I've moved past this by simply writing my own function named `mystricmp()` which is kind of distasteful but seems to work. Right now I'm mostly interested in why the compiler gave me such a funky message, and what would I be able to do about it if the function I had to hand-write weren't trivial?

Comment: Please, no pictures of text! It makes it harder to search for the error message, which you should be doing first. Also, you should extract and provide a [mcve], not a snippet with lots of missing context.

Comment: Not far from the Error List tab you should find the Output tab. This contains the full and unadulterated error message in plain text. Not only does this paste into Stack Overflow questions easily, the complete error message has details the Error List left out. Often these extra details crack the case wide open.

Comment: [`_stricmp` works fine in the latest VS 2019.](https://godbolt.org/z/M9KPTrMza)

Comment: Is FindExtension returning a char* pointer into a const char* buffer?  That's not safe coding.

Comment: Add the compile definition `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS` and use `stricmp` normally.

Comment: My guess would be you have `#define stricmp _stricmp` somewhere which is confusing the compiler

Comment: @ChrisMM Yes. That's why I though it was so odd when the compiler told me I had to use _stricmp instead of _stricmp. I don't have `_stricmp` #defined anywhere in my project.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Nope. I do have `#define STRICMP _stricmp` but not the other way around. On Linux I use `strcasecmp` instead of `_stricmp`.

Comment: @vacuumhead, if you select `_stricmp`, and select "Go To Definition" will it bring you to the correct one? The only other thing I can suggest is to suppress C4996 for that line.